# Can lines be drawn in ARcore without touching the screen?

Tags: android-studio, opengl-es, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I have to draw an app similar to Just A Line AR App but in my app,lines should be rendered as camera position is changed and should not require tapping/holding on the screen. How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean you want your line to be anchored in the scene - i.e. the points on the line follow the centre of the camera view as you move the device around.

Assuming this you can:

- at the start place an anchor some distance in front of the center of the camera, for example 1M in front.
- scheduled a job to repeat at some interval, e.g. 500ms and:
- place a new anchor, again 1M in front of the camera
- add the new anchor to a collection or list of anchors
- draw a line between the previous anchor and the current anchor in the list

This code will place an anchor in front of the camera:

```js
//Add an Anchor and a renderable in front of the camera       
Session session = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession();
float[] pos = { 0, 0, -1 };
float[] rotation = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };
Anchor anchor =  session.createAnchor(new Pose(pos, rotation));
anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
anchorNode.setRenderable(andyRenderable);
anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
```

Comment: Actually i wanted something like simulating touch and now i am using motionevent for this purpose.Thanks for the help though.